# Convert int to string with leading zeros

Tags: f#, leading-zero, padleft

I have an integer which I want to convert to a string with leading zeros.

So I have `1` and want to turn it into `01`. `14` should turn into `14` not `014`.

I tried:

```
let str = (string 1).PadLeft(2, '0') // visual studio suggested this one
let str = (string 1).PadLeft 2 '0'
let str = String.PadLeft 2 '0' (string 1)
```

But neither work :(
When I search for something like this with F# I get stuff with `printfn` but I don't want to print to stdout :/

Disclaimer: This is my first F#

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/) which returns a string rather than printing to stdout. Any of the `print` functions that start with an `s` return a string.

Use `%0i` to pad with zeroes. Add the length of the intended string between `0` and `i`. For example, to pad to four zeroes, you can use:

```fsharp
sprintf "%04i" 42

// returns "0042"
```

Comment: I totally missed the part with `s` in front of `print` :)

Comment: For some reason `%0i` doesn't work but `%02i` works like a charm

Comment: @Snæbjørn, `%0i` makes no sense because in order to zero-pad a string, you need to know to what length it should be padded.

Comment: How would I pad the string from a function param? `sprintf "%0[dynamic int param]i" 42`.

Comment: @Jecoms - to pad a variable number of characters you can use [String.PadLeft(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft) as in `(string 42).PadLeft(4, '0')`